# PHP Cannot connect to database config

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin, config

I have a folder structure like this:

```
|Home

|____|Admin

|__________|Pages

|

|

|db_config.php
```

Files located in the home directory, I set the connection to the db_config.php file as follows: 
`include("db_config.php");`

For files located in the pages directory, I set to:

`include("..\\..\\db_config.php");`

This setting works fine on my local and doesn't work when I up my website to 000webhost. What can I do to solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: what error shows up?  The file does not exist? A syntax error in the `db_config.php`? please clarify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply change

```
include("..\..\db_config.php");
```

to

```
include("../../db_config.php");
```

\ only works on windows, Linux uses / (which your host is using *probably*)
BTW, always use /, windows accepts it too.

Comment: don't forget about the even better global constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`.  Sometimes, windows _doesn't_ like those paths. Depends on where it's being run (CLI, apache, nginx, iis, etc..) Use `include('..' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. '..' .DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR. 'db_config.php');` to be safe.